# Which tagger could we use for future data? The code is in python

Tags: python, nltk, tagging

```
    import nltk
import math
from nltk.corpus import brown

brown_tagged_sents = brown.tagged_sents(categories='news')
size = int(math.floor(.9 * len(brown_tagged_sents)))
brown_tagged_0 = brown_tagged_sents[size:]
brown_tagged_1 = brown_tagged_sents[:size]

t0 = nltk.DefaultTagger('NN')
unigram_tagger_0 = nltk.UnigramTagger(brown_tagged_0,backoff=t0)
bigram_tagger_0 = nltk.BigramTagger(brown_tagged_0,backoff=unigram_tagger_0)


unigram_tagger_1 = nltk.UnigramTagger(brown_tagged_1,backoff=t0)
bigram_tagger_1 = nltk.BigramTagger(brown_tagged_1,backoff=unigram_tagger_1)

eval_A = bigram_tagger_0.evaluate(brown_tagged_0)
eval_B = bigram_tagger_0.evaluate(brown_tagged_1)
eval_C = bigram_tagger_1.evaluate(brown_tagged_0
```

Im trying to understand the whole meaning of tagger. In the code above which tagger would we use for future data and also just why?
Eval_A and Eval_B are two different evaluations of the same tagger. Can you explain why the higher evaluation score is higher? Eval A is 
Out[7]: 0.980962822685139
Eval B is Out[9]: 0.704168093591542

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the reason to split up the corpus is to hold-out some data so that you can evaluate the tagger. **So you shouldn't use the hold-out data to train your tagger.**

```
from nltk import UnigramTagger, BigramTagger, DefaultTagger
from nltk.corpus import brown

brown_news = brown.tagged_sents(categories='news')
trainsize = len(brown_news) * 90 / 100

train = brown_news[:trainsize]
test = brown_news[trainsize:]
```

There are also evaluation methods that considers the whole data without holding out, see [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29)

Then train your taggers using only the training data and evaluate using only the test data.

```
from nltk import UnigramTagger, BigramTagger, DefaultTagger
from nltk.corpus import brown

brown_news = brown.tagged_sents(categories='news')
trainsize = len(brown_news) * 90 / 100

train = brown_news[:trainsize]
test = brown_news[trainsize:]

tagger0 = DefaultTagger('NN')
unitag = UnigramTagger(train, backoff=tagger0)
bitag = BigramTagger(train, backoff=unitag)

print tagger0.evaluate(test)
print unitag.evaluate(test)
print bitag.evaluate(test)
```

[out]:

```
0.126283265225
0.835044353633
0.844712448919
```

Now you see that using the default tagger (`tagger0`) gets you low accuracy and using unigrams and bigrams gets you better results.

Comment: im a little confused about the Eval_A and Eval_B. Explain why the numbers are different. Is the difference one you would expect? That is, can you explain why the higher evaluation score is higher?

Comment: ALso I dont know if you answered it but what tagger would I use to see unseen data?

Comment: try going through this tutorial thoroughly and you will see the reasoning behind, http://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html

Comment: especially, section 6.3

Comment: so then why is ut[32]: <UnigramTagger: size=10920> bigger then the unigram tagger_0? so unigram tagger 1 is best to use for unseen data right